# How can I fill a scala Array with elements 3,4 ,5?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I try to fill in a random way an array but the program return Select(0.3 -> 3, 0.4 -> 4, 0.3 -> 5). The Select function should have return 3 with probability 0.3, 4 with probability 0.4 and so on.

```
object ex3
{
 def main(args: Array[String])
{ 
  val par = Array.fill(18)(Select( 0.3-> 3, 0.4->4, 0.3->5))
  println(par.deep.mkString("\n"))
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something simple like this:

```
val par = Array.fill(18)(fillarray())
println(par.mkString("\n"))

def fillarray(): Int = {
  scala.util.Random.nextInt(10) match{
    case 0 | 1 | 2 => 3
    case 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 => 4
    case _ => 5
  }
}
```